# Generating function of Catalan numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, generating-functions

I have the generating function $\hat{\beta}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k z^k$ where $C_k$ are Catalan numbers.

Now, for $|z|<1/4$ we've
$$\hat{\beta}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k \int x^{2k}\sigma(x) dx = \int \frac{1}{1-zx^2}\sigma(x) dx = \int \frac{1}{1-\sqrt{z}x}\sigma(x)dx,$$

where $\sigma(x) := \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{4-x^2}1_{|x|\le 2} $.

It's written that the third equality above (in the chain of equalities of the second $\hat{\beta}(z)$) follows from the fact that the support of $\sigma$ is the interval $[-2,2]$. I don't see why does that imply the third equality?

Can anyone please explain it to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone? Someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By expanding the term $\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{z}x}$ as a power series, you see that the odd powers (combined with the density function $\sigma(x)$), gives rise to an odd function, hence its integration over a symmetric interval around the origin is equal to zero.

Comment: I can see that now, thanks.